# Span is causing new line in this statement?

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have below line which is causing next line after text 100% and 99.8%

can anyone pls help me how can i display all this in one line side by side.

```html
<span style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;padding-left:800px;">99%>=<span style="color:#69BB1D;">GREEN</span><=100%, <span style="padding-left: 950px;">41%><span style="color:#FFD700;">YELLOW</span><99.8%,</span> <span style="color:#EE543D;padding-left:1100px;">RED</span><99.6%</span><br />
```

Comment: Try fixing the HTML to start

Comment: the padding is pushing it all far too far to the right

Comment: You have enough screen estate to fit in 2850px of `padding-left`?

Comment: Although I'm not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve, try adding `white-space: nowrap;` to the containing `span`. It'll stop the text from wrapping onto a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is "padding-left" in each span, it causes them to go to next line because they can't fit to the screen.

If you remove the padding -or at least decrease the value- they will be showing in one line side by side.

Example Here:
https://jsfiddle.net/zjbot272/

```
<span style="font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;">99%>=
<span style="color:#69BB1D;">GREEN</span><=100%, 
<span style="">41%>
<span style="color:#FFD700;">YELLOW</span><99.8%,</span> 
<span style="color:#EE543D;">RED</span><99.6%</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `white-space: nowrap;`. Anyway what you are doing is weird.

```
<span style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 800px; white-space: nowrap;">99%&gt;=<span style="color:#69BB1D;">GREEN</span>&lt;=100%, <span style="padding-left: 950px;">41%&gt;<span style="color:#FFD700;">YELLOW</span>&lt;99.8%,</span> <span style="color:#EE543D;padding-left:1100px;">RED</span>&lt;99.6%</span>
```